# Is this considered a recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The aim of the algorithm is to find the sum of the reciprocal of Sequence A with n numbers, using recursive algorithm.

```
findSum(A,n){
    Sum = 0
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1/A[0]
        }
    else {
        return A[n-1]
        Sum += 1/A[n-1]
    }
    return Sum
}
```

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: At no point does this function call itself, so there is no recursion

Comment: @UnholySheep i see, what should i change to make it recursive?

Comment: It isn't recursive. And putting code directly after a `return` doesn't make sense because it will never be reached.

Comment: @interjay how do I change it to make it recursive?

Comment: You add a call to the function from within the function body. I assume that `return A[n-1]` should be a recursive call instead of returning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other pointed out, you're never calling the function within itself, so no, it's not recursive.

There are multiple ways to go about this but you should think about what and where exactly are you summing up. You declared the sum within the function but you only take the reciprocal of the last item.

Think how would you go about the next iteration for the number before the last one. You can scope the sum outside the function, pass it as a parameter, or make the sum right in the return statement.

```
findSum(A, n){       
  return 1/A[n-1] + findSum(A, n-1)
}
```

Comment: Would you expect this code to do the same thing as the original code? Or for it to do what the OP wanted the function to do?

Comment: OP asked about recursion, with a non recursive code. They are trying to learn about recursion and while this may not be the best avenue that they took I feel we should encourage them to look in the right direction. Intentionally left incomplete since OP did actually have the right idea with the first if :)